# SQL statement to combine fact table and dimension table?

Tags: sql, fact-table

If I have a fact table and a dimension table, for example, as below:

### **fact_table**

fact_key

dim_key

revenue

cost

### **dimension_table**

dim_key

advertiser

product

Fact table has 4 rows and dimension table has 3 rows. How do I combine two tables?

Comment: Have you tried using a foreign key?

Comment: How would I do that? Just use the common dim_key row?

Comment: Yes - exactly. When you use query commands to fetch the joined tables, use `JOIN`s. Foreign key is something that's important to have when there's a relationship between tables. Check out the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a relationship between `fact_table` and `dimension_table`, you might want to do something like this:

```sql
alter table fact_table
    add constraint fact_table_fk
        foreign key (dim_key) references dimension_table(dim_key);
```

For the query you're asking for when selecting the rows, use `INNER JOIN` or any other [`JOIN` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT * FROM fact_table f
INNER JOIN dimension_table d
ON f.dim_key = d.dim_key
```